Missing subgraph in the PDG dot file generated by the plugin in Frama-c
I have been trying to use the pdg-dot plugin to help create a pdg graph of functions in the C file.
The command I used is
frama-c -pdg -pdg-dot pdg.dot "$file_path" -cpp-command "$gcc_cmd" -main function_analyzed

The c file I analyzed is from libxml2-2.9.4 project.
When I use the -main tag and specify a function to start it, it only creates a .dot file for the function and anything inside of it. When I tried to visualize the dot file in the vscode, it would missing the subgraph info called in this analyzed function. Here I'd like to give two examples.

Analyze the xmlNodeDump function (successful, xmlslave.c file)

int xmlNodeDump(xmlBufferPtr buf, xmlDocPtr doc, xmlNodePtr cur, int level,
            int format)
{
    xmlBufPtr buffer;
    int ret;
    int a = 2;
    if ((buf == NULL) || (cur == NULL))
        return(-1);
    buffer = xmlBufFromBuffer(buf);
    if (buffer == NULL)
        a++;
    ret = xmlBufNodeDump(buffer, doc, cur, level, format);
    xmlBufBackToBuffer(buffer);
    if (ret > INT_MAX)
        return(-1);
    return((int) ret);
}

the part of pdg dot file is showed below:
subgraph cluster_Call2378 { label="Call2378 : /* sid:2378 */\nbuffer = xmlBufFromBuffer(buf);";
                              fillcolor="#B38B4D"; style="filled"; 61;60;59;
     };
  subgraph cluster_Call2384 { label="Call2384 : /* sid:2384 */\ntmp = xmlBufNodeDump(buffer,doc,cur,level,format);";
                              fillcolor="#B38B4D"; style="filled"; 75;74;73;72;71;70;
     };
  subgraph cluster_Call2386 { label="Call2386 : /* sid:2386 */\nxmlBufBackToBuffer(buffer);";
                              fillcolor="#B38B4D"; style="filled"; 78;
     };


Analyze the installDirs function (problem one, runsuite.c file)

static void
installDirs(xmlNodePtr tst, const xmlChar *base) {
    xmlNodePtr test;
    xmlChar *name, *res;
    name = getString(tst, "string(@name)");
    if (name == NULL)
        return;
    res = composeDir(base, name);
    xmlFree(name);
    if (res == NULL) {
    return;
    }
    /* Now process resources and subdir recursively */
    test = getNext(tst, "./resource[1]");
    if (test != NULL) {
        installResources(test, res);
    }
    test = getNext(tst, "./dir[1]");
    while (test != NULL) {
        installDirs(test, res);
    test = getNext(test, "following-sibling::dir[1]");
    }
    xmlFree(res);
}


subgraph cluster_Call312 { label="Call312 : /* sid:312 */\nname = getString(tst,\"string(@name)\");";
                             fillcolor="#B38B4D"; style="filled"; 46;45;44;
     };

In the second example part, installdirsfunction call the installResources, it should be a subgraph in my understanding.

Initially, I thought it was a problem with command option, so I turned to eva command manual and used different command like -analysis-level and something else. However, it didn't work.
I try to look up some solutions but found nothing related.


(1) can you try editing the question to have a small reproducible example? (2) does the second analysis identify some parts as dead code?
